# Hdfs load Hbase Utility

Tags: hbase, hdfs, bulk-load

I have tried the following command to load the data from hdfs to hbase table. The job is loading the data into hbase table but not into the respective columns (meaning value of col1 is loaded into col2, value of col2 is loaded into col5 and so on). can someone help me with fixing this issue?

```
hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ImportTsv -Dimporttsv.separator=',' -Dimporttsv.columns='HBASE_ROW_KEY,col_family:col1,col_family:
col2,col_family:col3' 
hbase_table /hdfs location
```

Comment: add some rows from csv to the question

Comment: @AdamSkywalker thanks i got it. Thanks for your time